# past perfect tense with the conjunction "and"

Tags: conjunctions, past-perfect, parallelism

> Among those on his right was Bob, the guy that **had** days earlier **started** the lease and so **began** the first...

OR

> Among those on his right was Bob, the guy that **had** days earlier **started** the lease and so **begun** the first...

OR

> Among those on his right was Bob, the guy that **had** days earlier **started** the lease and so **had begun** the first...

The question really is, when the conjunction *and* lists two things that happened in the "perfect past", do I need a second *had*?

In this situation, the past is: Bob was on the right; while the "perfect past" or further past is: Bob was the guy that started the lease and (in so doing) began the first... (fill in the blank).

Which is right, or best? What is the rule?

Comment: When did the action really start, after the lease or before the lease?

Comment: I suspect that we will need the entire sentence. Rather than capitalise, please bold or italicise for emphasis.

Comment: @coleopterist: The bolding is **done**. (Of course, you could've done that, too. _If you've got the credit, make the edit._) :^)

Comment: @J.R. Thanks :) (I thought that the OP was still around ... Manager speak: "_when you need something done, delegate_" :)

Comment: What is the shortcode for bold and italics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a second *had* unless you wish to use one. Your example

> Among those on his right was Bob, the guy that **had** days earlier **started** the lease **and** so **begun** the first...

is perfectly grammatical and clear: "the guy ... had ... started ... and ... begun ..."

Even if you interject another clause the meaning and grammar are still fine:

> Among those on his right was Bob, the guy that **had** days earlier **started**, in a manner of speaking, the entire process of acquiring the lease, **and** so **begun** the first ...

The fact that you are using the the first *had* to service two verbs is still clear. Now, if you were to use *began* instead of *begun*, it would become a different sentence with a different meaning.

> Among those on his right was Bob, the guy that had days earlier started the lease, and so **began** the first...

Note the additional comma, inserted for clarity precisely to announce the fact that you are finished with the past perfect and beginning a clause using simple past. Presumably the omitted [...] material will discuss, in that new clause, the beginnings of some other event caused by the presence of Bob on the referenced individual's right side.

Comment: Thanks, this is clear. My example sentence above is imperfect, but I definitely intend the "so begun" clause to be an immediate effect of his starting the lease, all of which happened days ago, before he was standing to the right.

Comment: In other words, I will go with "begun".

Answer (score 1):

It's best to keep words that are linked by a conjunction as close as possible.

While I don't suppose the intended sentence is of the form:

> Among those on his right was Bob, the guy *who* **had** days earlier **started** the lease; and so began (/had begun) the first exchanges of the legal battle.

-as coleopterist says, we really aren't sure. (And doesn't one *open* / *take out* a lease?)

> Among those on his right was Bob, the guy who days earlier had taken out the lease and so begun the first...

would seem clearer. 'Begun' is needed as it is short for 'had begun' (referring to Bob); however, putting the grammatically correct 'had' in does lead to a garden-path scenario which I exploited in my first exemplar.

Comment: The lease began/opened question: indeed, my example sentence was made on the fly ;)

Answer (score -1):

Both versions (*began* and *begun*) are perfectly normal and valid.

Technically speaking, *begun* here should be preceded by *had*, but in fact there's no need to repeat it, because there's implied repetition of OP's preceding *HAD* anyway...

> I had drawn my gun and [**had**] started shooting before I recognised him.

---

Within the sentence fragment as given, *begin* could be [intransitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intransitive_verb) *(the first X began/had begun)*, or [transitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_verb) *(Bob began/had begun the first X)*, but this makes no difference to the answer.

Comment: Your “technically speaking” thing is technically wrong.  “I had already drunk and swum and sung and run, all before the firing squad came for me.  God thing, that.”  The auxiliary distributes across the conjunctive compound.  This is standard English.  There is no “technical” need to say “I had already drunk and had already swum and had already sung and had already run, all before the firing squad came for me.”  That’s nonsensical.

Comment: @tchrist: Rubbish. In your examples, you *need* at least one initial instance of "had" that can be assumed to have been "deleted" before the later verb forms. Otherwise you'd end up with *"I already sung before they shot me"*, which I suggest is indeed "technically incorrect" even if not everyone recognises it as particularly bad. But no-one endorses *"I taken my sleeping tablet before I went to bed"* - OP confuses the issue by citing a verb that people are often unsure about.

Comment: You seem to be arguing at a skewed right angle.  Nobody was talking about bare participles.